# How does one use ejs with node-webkit

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, ejs, embedded-javascript

in package.json

```
{
  "name": "_dubs",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "description": "GAME",
    "main": "views/index.ejs",
    ...
```

the app gives me this error "SyntaxError: unexpected token <"

Which I assume to be an issue due to ejs! (embedded js)

Any idea on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use anything other than pure html5 as your main file as far as node-webkit is concerned.  You would have to use the [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) module to first compile the content you want to appear in your document, then place said content into the document as you wish.

Here's an example that might help:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        var fs = require('fs');
        var ejs = require('ejs');

        fs.readFile('./index.ejs', function(err, data){
            if(err){
                document.body.innerHTML = err.toString();
                return;
            }

            var template = ejs.compile(data.toString());
            document.body.innerHTML = template({ name: 'world' });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Not yet rendered...
</body>
</html>
```

index.ejs

```
<div>hello, <%= name %>!</div>
```

Make sure that you have ejs installed as a dependency through npm, then when you run this, your body should then contain:

```
<div>hello, world!</div>
```